# Facebook apprequest dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using this code:

```
function newInvite(){
        var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request',
          to: user_ids, 
        });
      }
```

I need to store the request id's i get from this function

```
function loadFriends()
{
    //get array of friends
    FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,gender', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var divContainer=$('.facebook-friends');
                         var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");

for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    if(response.data[i].gender == 'male'){
         testdiv.innerHTML += response.data[i].id + '<br />';
    }
}
    });
}
```

How am i supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes simple,

```
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request',
          to: user_ids, 
        }, requestCallback);
```

source: [Request Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

**[EDIT]**

```
function newInvite(users){
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      to: users.join(',')
    });
}

function loadFriends()
{
    //get array of friends
    FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,gender', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var divContainer=$('.facebook-friends');
        var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");

        var  users = [];
        for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
            if(response.data[i].gender == 'male'){
                testdiv.innerHTML += response.data[i].id + '<br />';
            }
            users.push(response.data[i].id);
        }

        console.log(users)
        newInvite(users);        


    });
}
```

Comment: Well, can you please see this link here, because i'm getting frustrated with this thing... i've posted a thread and no solution yet..
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10781961/send-an-app-request-dialog-to-specific-array-of-ids

Comment: I accepted it as a logic, but it won't work...
I have an array of variables which collects some id's and want to pass it to the apprequest dialog.. it just wn't work..

Comment: wont work doesn't give any information to me. what is the error you are getting in console then?

Comment: Hey thanks... i get an error on this line..
      to: users.join(,),

Comment: Hey, at least it prompts out a message, even if it says, sorry, an error occurred... maybe because there is a limitation ?

Comment: Take a look here, it seems like it's looping continuously...
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Penelope-Test/411133928921438?sk=app_273511112737682

Comment: It didn't apply the filter i've put.. it seems like it sends the app to everyone, but how many friends do you have in facebook? because it seems to work only if you have less then 50 friends..

Comment: below 50.. shall we close this? as I have tested and it solves your problem??

Comment: Well thanks, thanks for all the work you did, it was great :)

Have a nice day! :)